# Casting object onto expected type with 'as' returns null

Tags: c#, casting, asp.net-core-webapi

Casting `public object Parameters { get; set; }` into expected object structure `request.Parameters as ParametersForA` returns null.

I tried to serialize `request.Parameters` and deserializing it into `ParametersForA` type with use of `Newtonsoft.Json`, what forks perfectly fine, but it still not satisfy me as I would like understand previous failure.

This is code i test:

C#

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ObjectCasting.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Request request)
        {
            if (request.OperationCode == "A")
            {
                var obj = request.Parameters as ParametersForA; // <<< null problem
                return Ok(obj);
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public string OperationCode { get; set; }
        public object Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParametersForA
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is HTTP POST json request body:

json

```
{
    "OperationCode": "A",
    "Parameters": {
        "Age": 25,
        "Name": "Caroline"
    }
}
```

I wish to understand why casting does not work here.

For specified, unique `OperationCode` in the future I will expect different casting destinations and `Parameters` json request structure respectively.

[image: request]

Comment: Why dont you define Parameters property as ParametersForA.Why is it defined as object?

Comment: `request.Parameters` seems to be a `JToken`. What is the type the debugger indicates? That part you just cut of the screenshot.

Comment: For specified, unique `OperationCode` in the future I will expect different casting destinations and Parameters json request structure respectively.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman `request.Parameters.GetType` in the first line of POST methot indicates `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` type.

Comment: So how do you expect that to be `ParametersForA`?

Comment: You can not cast `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` into a `ParametersForA` by as casting

Comment: You could cast it to `JObject` and then `ToObject<ParametersA>()`. I wouldn't recommend that though.

Comment: Ok, @Patrick Hofman, @Hasan Emrah Süngü are there some workaround for `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`?

Comment: You may use some `dynamic` magic here, or a more common `Dictionary<string,string>` method (change a type of `Request.Parameters` to `dynamic` or `Dictionary<string,string>`)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in type of `Parameters` property. It is `object` and the actual type is `JObject` when request is received.

You should cast using `ToObject<SomeType>()` method to cast `JObject` to needed type:

```
var obj = (request.Parameters as JObject).ToObject<ParametersForA>();
```

To cast to different types based on `OperationCode`:

```
switch(request.OperationCode)
{
    case "1":
       // cast to one type and process
    case "2":
       //cast to another type and process
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do not expect to be tied to specified type as you suggest @Roman Doskoch

Comment: that is what I looked for! Only one thing to make code compilable `var obj = ((JObject)request.Parameters).ToObject<ParametersForA>();`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting follows certain rules, for reference types there should be hierarchy to be able to cast one type into another.

In your case, you can't cast it because your `Parameter` is actualy a `JToken`, which can't be directly casted to `ParameterA`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions):

> Implicit conversions: No special syntax is required because the
>   conversion is type safe and no data will be lost. Examples include
>   conversions from smaller to larger integral types, and conversions
>   from derived classes to base classes.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The poster just wants to know why casting (converting) is not working. This is what is explained here.

Comment: Then maybe he should, and once he does he should be able to figure out how to make it work (or get around it).

Comment: @peeyush singh, your post was also valuable as it reminded mi basic rule I forgot in 
fervor of battle.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no value to you maybe. You can flag my answer to be closed if you think it provides no value instead of protesting and asking why people see value in it.

Comment: @peeyushsingh, there is no value right now. But if you add just a little explanation to it (so it start looking like an answer) - there will be a value. I.e. _"You can't cast it because your Parameter is actualy a JToken, which can't be directly casted to ParameterA. Here is the docs:"_

Comment: @vasily.sib I took the liberty to put your comment in the answer actually.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman , vasily.sib,  thanks, always feels nice when someone helps out.